# IIS worker process and host headers

Tags: iis, virtualhost, host-headers

I am building a multi tenancy site in ASP.net. It will has three host headers.

My understanding is that when a request comes to www.siteA.com, ISS will spin up a worker process for the for the application.

But what happens with a requests comes in for site www.siteB.com, will it be the same worker process or will a new one start?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS default Maximum worker process for an Application Pool is 1. 
So in that case it will work on the same worker process.

But for you knowledge please have a look at this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151251/asp-net-web-garden-how-many-worker-processes-do-i-need